# Client side validation on excel file is failing in testcafe

Tags: validation, testing, automated-tests, client-side, testcafe

Our website is developed on react,after uploading excel,excel validation is happening in front end using third party library[sheet JS].Manually its working but testcafe automation is failing.Automation is hanging while client side validation is in progress.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with this amount of detail?

Comment: Please share the TestCafe test code and your page URL or an example page that we could use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry sir,our product is in alpha stage,as per company policy we cant share URL and code.Issue is "client side related validation is failing in testcafe[hammerhead server] and its hanging in that particular test case".Please inform how to debug these type of issues.

Comment: I'm afraid I need more information to determine the cause of the issue. It looks like a TestCafe bug, and if it is, it will be difficult to give any advice on how to debug the issue. We'll need to deal with it on our side.

Comment: Sir getting below error in console.google drive link is "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KwDVjT7RC65OTHddV8Z0_eJ6ULV4jMzP/view?usp=sharing".Please inform how to debug these type of issues.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the error message you shared and this issue looks similar to https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2895.

TestCafe stores additional data in the `localStorage`. If `localStorage` fills up, the tests might hang.

To prevent TestCafe from saving logs to `localStorage`, run the following code before every test (during user setup):

```js
const disableTestcafeLogStorage = ClientFunction(() => {
  window["%testCafeDriverInstance%"]._onConsoleMessage = () => {};
});

await disableTestcafeLogStorage();
```

For more information, see [this thread](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2942).